# Show nested UL using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, this

I have a nested ul to make a sub menu. I want a click event to show the child ul and keep the others collapsed.

HTML

```
<div class="sideMenu">  
<ul>
<li class="titledUl"><b>Dashboard</b>
                </li>
                    <ul class="subUl">
                        <li>Dash Tool 1
                        </li>
                        <li class="subUl">Dash Tool 2
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>   
            <ul>
                <li class="titledUl"><b>User Managment</b>
                </li>
                    <ul class="subUl">
                        <li>UM Tool 1
                        </li>
                        <li>UM Tool 2
                        </li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

jQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );

$('.titledUl').click(function() {
    console.log('clicked')
    $(this).closest('.subUl').show();
    console.log("should show")
});
});
```

It shows all my console logs when I click on the parent ul. (also the sub uls are hidden using css display none)

Thanks!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. </li> <ul class="subUl"> <-- you cannot put a UL  (or anything else) outside an LI

Comment: You don't need to use JavaScript or jQuery at all to do this kind of interactive menu. Check out CssMenuMaker.com and especially this tutorial: http://cssmenumaker.com/css-flyout-menus

Comment: Along the lines of what DOK said, have you checked out bootstrap?  They have nav menu support.

Comment: I refactored my Html. I was able to figure out the jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Hello your job done here: http://jsfiddle.net/webcarvers/RYvGv/

HTML:

```
<div class="sideMenu">
    <ul>
        <li class="titledUl"><b>Dashboard</b>
         <ul class="subUl">
            <li>Dash Tool 1</li>
            <li>Dash Tool 2</li>
        </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li class="titledUl"><b>User Managment</b>
        <ul class="subUl">
            <li>UM Tool 1</li>
            <li>UM Tool 2</li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.subUl{
    display:none;
}
.titledUl{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.titledUl').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('ul').find(".subUl").slideToggle(500);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the help of you all. Thank you!

New HTML

```
            <div class="sideMenu">  
            <ul>
                <li class="titledUl"><b>Dashboard</b>
                    <ul class="subUl">
                        <li>Dash Tool 1
                        </li>
                        <li class="subUl">Dash Tool 2
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>   
            <ul>
                <li class="titledUl"><b>User Managment</b>
                <ul class="subUl">
                        <li>UM Tool 1
                        </li>
                        <li>UM Tool 2
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

New jQuery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   console.log( "ready!" );

$('.titledUl').click(function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    $(this).children().show();
    console.log("should show");
});

});
```